# Pass unicode string from VB.net to C++ dll

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have tried a lot of things but I cannot get this to work. I can pass and receive ordinary strings (char*) to C++, but I cannot receive Unicode strings (`w_char_t *`) in C++.

Here are some bits of the code on c++

```
__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall readFile(const w_char_t *file_path)
```

on VB.net

```
Public Declare Function readFile Lib "MyDll.dll" Alias "_readFile@4" (ByVal file_path As String) As Integer
```

when I change `w_char_t` to `char` I receive the correct string.

I have found a lot of material on VB6, but not for VB.net

Any help greatly appreciated.

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Declare Unicode Function readFile Lib "MyDll.dll" Alias "_readFile@4" (ByVal file_path As String) As Integer
```

Also, your C++ code has dllexport not dllimport, right?

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot. (says dllexport too)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting UnicodeString to String (by using some System Defined Function), and then pass that string or char* to C++ DLL.

Hope this will work.